# Korn shell metacharacters: What does !(some text) mean?

Tags: unix, ksh

Trying to figure out how ksh is processing the construct !(text). For example,

$ echo !(hello)

produces a list of files in the current directory (similar to the output of an ls command, except it's sorted into columns rather than rows). It doesn't matter what text is in the parens, the output is the same.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what the command is actually doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It echoes all files except hello. You can also use wildcards like `echo !(*.java)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more detailed information.  For more info, look in the "file name generation" section of the ksh man page (bash works the same way). See here for more patterns:  https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sh.1.asp

```
A sub-pattern begins with a ?, *, +, @, or ! character followed by a pattern-list 
enclosed in parentheses. Pattern-lists themselves can contain sub-patterns. 
The following list describes valid sub-patterns.

?(pattern-list) 
        Matches exactly zero or exactly one occurrence of the specified pattern-list.

*(pattern-list) 
        Matches zero or more occurrences of the specified pattern-list.

+(pattern-list) 
        Matches one or more occurrences of the specified pattern-list.

@(pattern-list) 
        Matches exactly one occurrence of the specified pattern-list.

!(pattern-list) 
        Matches any string that does not match the specified pattern-list.
```

So for your example, when the shell sees the unquoted exclamation point, followed by parenthesis it goes into file name matching mode, then it displays files in the current directory that do not match "hello".